# Vue.js EventListenner

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm completely newbie in Vue.js and i've to use it in order to complete a programming task.
i'm getting in trouble trying to call pure JS in Vue file.
I just have to add an event listener on an element, there is an example:

```
document.getElementById("mp_addCloud").addEventListener('hover',function(){
alert(1);
})
```

Can i do it without use v-on in the frontend? Maybe calling an annonymous function? (I wanna do it without any user call action)
Thanks

Comment: Despite having answered, I am curious: Why not use the v-on handler?

Comment: If you're using document.getElementById in Vue.js, you're doing it wrong.  Use components instead, or, at worse, refs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In the [Mounted() hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) of the component that contains the element `#mp_addCloud`, you can say something to the effect of:

`this.$el.querySelector('#mp_addCloud').addEventListener(...)`

Clarification: in that statement, `this` is the Vue component. `$el` is that component's root element.

Edit: as @cccn stated in their answer, the event name is `mouseover`, not `hover`.

Edit 2: If you want to use the v-on directive, you can wrap the event in an anonymous function or call a method on the Vue element:

**Anonymous function:**
`<my-element v-on:mouseover="() => alert('1')"></my-element>`

**Via method:**
`<my-element v-on:mouseover="myAlertFunction"></my-element>`

With this approach, you'll need to define your method in the Vue component's methods:

```
methods: {
   myAlertMethod() {
    alert('1');
  }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Vue. You just use wrong event. Try with `mouseover` instead of `hover`.

Comment: The asker is also complaining about "getting in trouble trying to call pure JS in Vue file", so in that particular case is not Vue thing.